# Build script compiles few coffee script files and skips few

Tags: javascript, linux, build, coffeescript

My host Machine is Windows. I have code in my host machine. 
I have virtual box that has linux os and runs build scripts. Part of build script compiles it and gives java script.
Issue : Few of the files are not getting compiled and I don't see any error.

Comment: You have to provide exact information about the build system: build script, build environment, any additional detail.

Comment: I'm running build script using $ Bash ../../build.xml . I am developing a web app. Writing backbone using coffee script. My IDE is in windows. I am sharing my files to virtually hosted linux machine.

Comment: `bash ../../build.xml`? XML files are not executable by bash, are you using some special build system? (CMake, Maven...)

Comment: I got this resolved. Issue was with coffee-script. I re-installed them and it works fine now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please do check if all the scripts are getting compiled once you have coffee script installed. If its not compiling few, first step is to re-install coffee script or check if coffee script is installed properly.

Once confirmed that the coffee script installation is fine, then debug issue. This will save time.